# ASP.Net core JWT Bearer authentication with Keycloak StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I'm using .Net core 6 with Keycloak and I wanted to implement JWT authorization.

I've been following this tutorial which is written for .Net 5 - but I was adapting it to .Net 6:

https://blog.devgenius.io/security-in-react-and-webapi-in-asp-net-core-c-with-authentification-and-authorization-by-keycloak-f890d340d093

So, I added this class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mediere_API.Authorization
{
    public static class ConfigureAuthentificationServiceExtensions
    {
        private static RsaSecurityKey BuildRSAKey(string publicKeyJWT)
        {
            RSA rsa = RSA.Create();

            rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(

                source: Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyJWT),
                bytesRead: out _
            );

            var IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);

            return IssuerSigningKey;
        }

        public static void ConfigureJWT(this IServiceCollection services, bool IsDevelopment, string publicKeyJWT)
        {
            var AuthenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

            AuthenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(o =>
              {

                  o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                  {
                      ValidateAudience = false,
                      ValidateIssuer = true,
                      ValidIssuers = new[] { "http://localhost:8080/realms/MyRealm" },
                      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                      IssuerSigningKey = BuildRSAKey(publicKeyJWT),
                      ValidateLifetime = true
                  };

                  o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                  {
                      OnTokenValidated = c =>
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine("User successfully authenticated");
                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                      },
                      OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                      {
                          c.NoResult();

                          c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                          c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

                          if (IsDevelopment)
                          {
                              return c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString());
                          }
                          return c.Response.WriteAsync("An error occured processing your authentication.");
                      }
                  };

              });
        }
    }
}
```

and my Program.cs

```
using mediere_API.Authorization;
using mediere_API.DataLayer;
using mediere_API.DataLayer.Repository.Implementations;
using mediere_API.DataLayer.Repository.Interfaces;
using mediere_API.Processors.Implementations;
using mediere_API.Processors.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Servicii
builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
builder.Services.ConfigureJWT(true, "SECRET");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Postgres");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EfDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));


var app = builder.Build();
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

and above the controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 6.0.8.

Now, after those settings, when I do a a GET request with a valid token I get:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

and I couldn't figure out why.

Does anybody have an idea why would that happen and how should I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that some other component already wrote the response to the client. One that happens you can no longer change the status code (it would be meaningless).

You can find out what is writing to the response by adding a middleware like this at the beginning of your pipeline and running the application under a debugger:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    return next();
});
```

Then you should be able to look at the call stack and see which component is writing to the response.

Comment: I added it into Program.cs as the first app.something statement and I ran it with the debugger. I got: https://imgur.com/a/n4t0Ny7 . Sorry - I'm kind of a beginner in ASP.Net :)

Comment: The break point needs to be inside of the second callback. Where I have the call to Debugger.Break.

Comment: Here's the stack trace: https://imgur.com/a/uWHvDbr

Comment: Can you find which two threads are conflicting?

Comment: Authentication failed is writing to the response